# Css class in react and scope in component

Tags: create-react-app

I have a component in React (in a app created with create-react-app cli) with a css file and I have impoerted it with

> import './Card.css';

I have noted that if I have a .container selector in css file it is applied in all app but I want that the css file is visible only for the .js component file. 
Is this the normal behavior of css file in React?

Comment: Scoping classnames is the job of another library, this is unrelated to React. You might be looking for [PostCSS](https://github.com/postcss/postcss).

Comment: See ["Adding a CSS Preprocessor"](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-a-css-preprocessor-sass-less-etc) since you are using create-react-app.

Comment: Thanks for the links :)

Comment: @RossAllen: what do you think about https://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2016/07/css-modules-webpack-react/ ?

Comment: I think you should prefix classnames inside component-specific CSS files with the name of the component, and then namespacing is solved for you by the file system. I'd see how far that gets you before trying to add a preprocessor.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. I was thinking that prepocessor doesn't solve the problem of scoping it only converts scss in css, or am I wrong?

Comment: "Preprocessor" is a generic term, it can do whatever transformation it wants and output plain old CSS. Scoping would happen in a pre-processing step. PostCSS is a preprocessor.